# Frama-c [kernel] user error: Length of array is zero. This extension is unsupported

Tags: c, frama-c

I am trying to generate PDG of a c program using this command

```
frama-c -machdep x86_64 -pdg -cpp-command 'gcc -C -E -std=c99 -I. ' try.c
```

but I get this following error

```
[kernel] preprocessing with "gcc -C -E -std=c99 -I.   try.c"

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap.h:47:[kernel] warning: Calling undeclared function __builtin_bswap32. Old style K&R code?

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap.h:111:[kernel] warning: Calling undeclared function __builtin_bswap64. Old style K&R code?

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl-linux.h:316:[kernel] user error: Length of array is zero. This extension is unsupported

[kernel] user error: skipping file "try.c" that has errors.

[kernel] Frama-C aborted: invalid user input.
```

How do I solve this?
Update:
The C code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n,m;
    int i,j;
    int flag=1;

    scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);

    int a[n][m];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        if(a[i][0]==a[i+1][0])
        {
            flag=0;
            break;
        }

        for(j=0;j<m-1;j++)
        {
                if(a[i][j]!=a[i][j])
                {
                    flag=0;
                    break;
                }
        }
        if(flag==1)
        {
            continue;
        }

        else
            break;
    }

    if(flag==1)
        printf("YES");
    else
        printf("NO");

    return 0;
}
```

The version of frama-c used is

> Version: Fluorine-20130601 Compilation date: Mon Dec 23 22:50:26 UTC 2013
>
> Share path: /usr/share/frama-c (may be overridden with FRAMAC_SHARE variable)
>
> Library path: /usr/lib/frama-c (may be overridden with FRAMAC_LIB variable)
>
> Plug-in paths: /usr/lib/frama-c/plugins (may be overridden with FRAMAC_PLUGIN variable)

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code, but the text of the error let suspect that you are trying to use Variable Length Array and that your compiler does not support it.

Comment: As mentioned by @SergeBallesta, without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's difficult to give a precise answer. This includes the code, the command line and the Frama-C version you're using. Besides, it appears that you rely on the standard headers provided by your system rather than the ones of Frama-C itself.  These headers are likely to contain compiler-specific constructions, that may or may not be supported by Frama-C.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code as well as the frama-c version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zero-length arrays are supported since Frama-C Aluminium (released in may 2016). This is the relevant excerpt from the Changelog:

```
 -! Cil       [2015/12/02] Changes in the handling of incomplete structs and
              zero-length arrays. Initialization of incomplete (completely
              undefined) structs is now duly rejected. Several compiler
              extensions to the C99 standard (empty initializers,
              zero-length arrays, etc.) now require a GCC or MSVC machdep
              (e.g. -machdep gcc_x86_32).
```

As indicated, you should use a GCC machdep, namely `gcc_x86_64` in your case.

Comment: I am using -machdep x86_64, gcc_x86_64 gives me an user error [kernel] user error: unsupported machine gcc_x86_64. Try one of x86_64 x86_32 ppc_32
                     x86_16.

Comment: Ok, I am using flourine version, I will try the aluminium version which seems to be the latest